# faild to initialise firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization

when ever i run my app i get this error in the logs

[ Easy Localization] [WARNING] Localization key [Failed to initialise firebase!] not found

but the key is in my assets/translates in en.json as `"Failed to initialise firebase!": "Failed to initialise firebase!",` and in ar.json as `"Failed to initialise firebase!": "فشل تهيئة Firebase!",`

when i run my app i get the error  `Failed to initialise firebase!`   on my screen

this  is my code

```
await UserPreference.init();
runApp(
  MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      Provider<CartDatabase>(
        create: (_) => CartDatabase(),
      )
    ],
    child: EasyLocalization(
        supportedLocales: [Locale('en'), Locale('ar')],
        path: 'assets/translations',
        fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
        saveLocale: true,
        useOnlyLangCode: true,
        useFallbackTranslations: true,
        child: MyApp()),
  ),
);
```

and this is also the other part of the code that shows the error [Failed to initialise firebase! screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKJP3.jpg)

```
Show error message if initialization failed
if (_error) {
  return MaterialApp(
      locale: context.locale,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 25,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              Text(
                'Failed to initialise firebase!'.tr(),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 25),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ));
}
```

i tried checking to see if i wrote the key exactly the same as it is in my main.dart To fix this issue,  ensured that the localization key "Failed to initialise firebase!" is present in the localization files for all the supported languages in my app by Verify Localization Files

i ensured that the key is spelled correctly and matches the casing used in the warning message due to Localization keys been case-sensitive,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added your translation files to `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/translates/
```

and that you await for initializng EasyLocalization like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  // ...
}
```

It is also common to write keys as "lower_case_and_no_space", so I recommend changing that. If you are using json files for translations I would also recommend using code generation EasyLocalization package provides. You need to run
`flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -S "assets/translates" -O "lib/translations" -f keys -o translations.g.dart` in your terminal an then you can use your keys more easily:

en.json:

```
{
  "firebase_error": "Failed to initialise firebase!"
}
```

somewhere in your app:

```
import 'translations/translations.g.dart';

// ...
Text(
  LocaleKeys.firebase_error.tr(),
)
```

for more info look here: https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization

Comment: after following your instructions am still getting the same results and am getting errors when i use  code generation in the translations.g.dart file

Comment: I noticed that you wrote you have your translations file under assets/translates and in EasyLocalization widget you have `path: 'assets/translations'`. Change either of those and ensure paths match in all three places: in EasyLocalization widget, in `pubspec.yaml` and in file explorer (actual path). Correct the path in code generator as well. Hope that helps :)

Comment: i meant to write assets/translations my bad for the confusion.the issue is still persisting though